# How to dispose a mock object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a mock object that starts a timer and needs to be disposed of in my test. What is the proper way to dispose the mock object? In my class to be mocked, I have:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Stop and dispose timer here.
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
}
```

So now in my test, I need to mock the object, use it, and then make sure it's getting disposed. I know I can just set `CallBase = true`, but I'm not sure if this is the correct (industry standard) way of doing things:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ObjectWithTimer>() { CallBase = true };

    using (var foo = mock.Object)
    {
        foo.DoSomething(); // This consequently starts a timer.
    } // Here, Dispose() will be called.
}
```

When the using block ends, `Dispose()` is called, which calls the base `Dispose(bool)`. However, is it possible to do this disposing without adding `CallBase = true` to my mock? This is not ideal when I need mock to override other methods.

Comment: Reading your post a second time, I'm not so sure anymore if you want to test another class, which uses the ObjectWithTimer, or the ObjectWithTimer class itself?

Comment: Hi Desty. In this case, I would like to test the ObjectWithTimer class itself.

Comment: I didn't get it yet, if you want to test the ObjectWithTimer class, why do you need to mock it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problems gets solved if you loose the coupling between the two classes, so that the mock is more generic. This can be done if your class under test does not use `ObjectWithTimer` directly, but an interface which gets implemented by `ObjectWithTimer`.

Example:

```
public interface IObjectWithTimer : IDisposable
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class ObjectWithTimer : IObjectWithTimer
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassUnderTest
{ 
    public ClassUnderTest(IObjectWithTimer timer)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void ThisShouldCallDisposeOnTimer()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then your test code looks like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldCallDispose()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IObjectWithTimer>();
    var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(mock.Object);

    classUnderTest.ThisShouldCallDisposeOnTimer();

    mock.Verify(x => x.Dispose(), Times.Once());
}
```

This way your test is completely detached from the timer disposing logic, which is really not what you want to test.

Comment: This was the most helpful in finding a solution. Losing the coupling between the classes put me in a better spot to test them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

By using `new Mock<ObjectWithTimer>()`, your code isn't fully separated from the implementation of that class, since that method gives a mock class derived from your concrete implementation, which (as you have clearly worked out) isn't really what you want your mocks to be doing.

Create an Interface for `ObjectWithTimer`. The interface should include whatever is public about that class. Since the class is `IDisposable`, your interface should be derived from that interface. Change the code which depends on that class to depend instead on the interface, and change the test to mock the interface rather than the class.

Now that you're using a proper Mock object, your test may need to define how that mock is expected to behave. This is normal when using mock objects, and it's important to mock the behaviour correctly, or your test will be worthless (it could pass when the real code could fail).

The calling code now has complete separation from the implementation of that interface, so it no longer matters how the concrete class (ObjectWithTimer) is implemented.